# Rack static not working with map

Tags: ruby, rack

I have a simple rack app:

```
map "/foo" do
  use Rack::Static, 
    :urls => [""], :root => 'public', :index => 'admin.html'
  run lambda {|env| [200, {}, []]}
end
```

When I browse to `lvho.st/foo` I get `404 File not Found` but if I go to `lvho.st/foo/admin.html` it's loaded just fine.

I want it to serve `admin.html` at `lvho.st/foo`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have whitnessed yourself that even though `lvho.st/foo` might not work, `lvho.st/foo/` (with a trailing slash) however does! So the question is how to either skip checking for the trailing slash or append it to all requests. The problem can be solved with a small `.htaccess` redirect on a Passenger / Apache server, but we're in Ruby, so here's the Ruby solution - the **[rack-slashenforce gem](https://github.com/tkellen/rack-slashenforce)**.

Run this in your project folder (or append it to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`):

```
gem install rack-slashenforce
```

Then your Ruby file would look like this:

```
require 'rack-slashenforce'

# Make sure you declare this outside the map block
use Rack::AppendTrailingSlash
map "/foo" do
  use Rack::Static, :urls => [""], :root => 'public', :index => 'admin.html'
  run lambda {|env| [200, {}, []]}
end
```

Now every call to `lvho.st/foo` will get a slash appended! And everything should work fine.